# return the data at webservices

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, return

i wanted to pass the string to my query, it able to display all my record if i type in the 'WHERE' part by my self. so i modified it so that user can search the query based on their need... code as below:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

public class EmployeeWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();

    public EmployeeWebService ()
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection conn = null;
        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection(cs);
            //search the data based on the data key in
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE userType = '" + ?? + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            conn.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                list.Add(new Employee { fullName = reader["fullName"].ToString(), password = reader["password"].ToString(), userType= reader["userType"].ToString() });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Trace.Warn("Error", "error in getcustomer()", e);
        }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public Employee GetEmployeeDetails(string userType)
    {
        //i need to return this data back to the query
        string type = userType.ToString();
        return type;
    }
}
```

**Error Message**

```
Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Employee'
```

Comment: userType is string and you are again call ToString() on it. What exactly you are passing to the method can you add GetEmployeeDetails method call in question

Comment: Don't use string concatenation for your query - use Parameters. Or else: [Exploits of a Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return multiple employee objects

```
[WebMethod]
public List<Employee> GetEmployeeDetails(string userType)
{
   //search the member table looking for a matching userType value
   string sql = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE userType = '" + ?? + "'";
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
   conn.Open();
   List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();
   reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

   while (reader.Read())
   {
      var emp = new Employee(
          { 
              fullName = reader["fullName"].ToString(), 
              password = reader["password"].ToString(), 
              userType = reader["userType"].ToString()
          });

      employeeList.Add(emp);
   }

   reader.close();
   return employeeList;
}
```

Comment: it;s not a single record, it's a list of record, expect the result will be more than 1. and i use connection string which connect to my sql database

Comment: you can use the generic list to return the list of employees. you function return type will be

List<Employee> Employee GetEmployeeDetails(string userType)

and you return the list. you can also use Employee[] array for returning employee object.

Comment: " List<Employee> Employee = GetEmployeeDetails(string userType) " , where should i apply this?

Comment: check my altered answer for returning list of employees.

Comment: hi, thanks for the update, but i get the error for fullName and password. Error:The name 'fullName' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Please don't ever do data queries like this! Use SQL Query Parameters, not string concatenation! Additionally, maybe you could wrap your IDisposable members in a `using` statement?